# Windows Server 2008 R2 Bulk Activiation

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, licensing

Is there a way to activate a group of Windows 2008 R2 Servers without logging into each one and typing the key?

This will be the same key for all the servers and they are all on Active Directory (So Maybe AD or Group Policy?).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to take a look to http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/Windows-Server-License-Manager-Script-slmgrvbs.html

Comment: Specifically, `slmgr.vbs –ipk 00000-00000-00000-00000-00000` to enter a key (if not included in install) and `slmgr.vbs -ato` to activate.

Answer (score 3):

While Radius & JScott's answer is the most appropriate for smaller environments; larger deployments should look into [Microsoft's Key Management Service](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd772269.aspx) for fully automated key/activation and license tracking. It does require [volume licenses](http://www.microsoft.com/licensing/existing-customers/product-activation.aspx).